# Swap issue and "read swap header failed" for /swapfile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap, nagios

My Swap memory shows `SWAP critical 0% free` on NMS.

I tried:

```
 `$ swapon --show`
```

but nothing showed up. I went on to do:

```
$ free -m
         total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      7873        2858        1151        1295        3863        3373
Swap:        0           0           0
```

Then:

```
$ swapon -a
swapon: /swapfile: insecure permissions 0644, 0600 suggested. 
swapon: /swapfile: read swap header failed
```

Comment: How did you create this swapfile? You can solve the permissions warning with `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE !  **1)** if nothing showed following the cmd `swapon --show`, it means you do not have a swap partition. **2)** this is corroborated by the output of `free -m`. **3)** Apparently you (or some process) created a swapfile, whose permissions are `0644` instead of `0600`. Change permissions with: `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile` or whatever the path to the swapfile is.

Comment: .. and I see that Panki just beat all of us to the permission change instruction.

Answer (score 7):

```
chmod 0600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```